# Bookmarklet to run different functions depending on times clicked

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, delay, bookmarklet

Is it possible to design a bookmarklet to run different scenarios based on the number of times it was clicked?

I tried to do this via addEventListener when clicked and setTimeout(main, 5000), then counting the eventListeners' fires when main() finally runs. It works after a fashion, but there are two problems with this approach:

1. Clicks are caught and counted if the bookmarklet is invoked as a link on a webpage, but not, of course, if clicked on Bookmark Bar. This is unresolvable, I believe; the number of clicks has to be evaluated when the last main function runs somehow…
2. Say, I clicked the bookmarklet 3 times; main() runs 3 times spaced 5000ms apart. How do I make it run only the once? And only the last one at that, to resolve the problem in #1? The way I do it is so cumbersome as to be all but useless, and is prone to racing besides.

The main question though is that I feel my approach, even if viable, is far too clumsy. I'm aware I can use, say, prompt() and have the user enter the number of a scenario, or render a menu and click a required scenario, but is there a way to do that based simply on the number of clicks / snippet runs within a given time frame?

Comment: Please add the code of your bookmarklet to the question, without that it's really hard to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you need:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  window.bmClicked = window.bmClicked ? window.bmClicked + 1 : 1;

  clearTimeout(window.bmTimeout);

  window.bmTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('window.bmClicked: ', window.bmClicked);

    window.bmClicked === 1 && functionOne();
    window.bmClicked === 2 && functionTwo();
    window.bmClicked === 3 && functionThree();

    window.bmClicked = null;
  }, 500);

  function functionOne() {
    console.log('functionOne');
  }

  function functionTwo() {
    console.log('functionTwo');
  }

  function functionThree() {
    console.log('functionThree');
  }
})();
```

Comment: I think I learned more from this than from a week of experimenting. Thank you very much, it's perfect.